# Where to get started for developing android OS?

Tags: android, operating-system

I want to get started working with android (not apps for it but with the OS) and I wanted to know where I can find something like a book that explains how it works. Explaining what kernel android OS uses how it works and such and reviewing some source code wouldn't hurt. Also should I know any other languages besides java?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android is an `open source OS`, and you can get all source code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/?format=HTML).

You can also add `Android Resource Navigator` in your chrome, and when you browsing `developer.android.com` classes, it will have `view source` as following:

[image]

Comment: I think you can get some idea form [here](http://www.99droid.com/android-kernel-development-tutorial-let-the-development-begin/).

Comment: Google didn't help me out this time but thanks so much and another tutorial (like a book or something) would be great.                                                                                                           Thanks again.

Comment: LOL, Maybe Google can help you next time. I am glad to help, cheers!

Comment: I looked it up but sadly he stopped at like two tuts.                                                           Do you knows and alternative?

Comment: Do you mean using `Android Resource Navigator`?

Comment: No the same like before but he stopped at 2 articles.                                            To develop the kernel, or the OS.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently in the same boat. I would recommend as a start using the official tutorials from Google located [here](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html)

I looked over that and followed some of the tutorials until I became comfortable enough to go ahead to the different libraries and read through them while determining if they were useful for my needs or not. I then would start a new project for the questionable items to test them out and get familiar. You will find a few different libraries do similar things.

Comment: That link concerns app development, not OS development

Comment: @ChrisStratton The wording of the original question was confusing. Thanks for the help clarifying the situation.

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for something different.